# List<Object> to Stream<List<Object>> Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, stream

How to Convert List to Stream<List> in Dart , Flutter. I am trying to convert List of Objects to Stream List.

Comment: check the existing `Stream` constructors

Comment: You should try map instead.

Comment: If you really want: `Stream<List<Object>> makeStream(List<Object> list) async* { yield list; }` However, converting a `List<T>` to a `Stream<List<T>>` seems like a rather strange thing to do.  If you already have a `List`, why would you want to wrap it in a `Stream`?  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this :

```
 Stream<List<String>> _currentString = watchForSomeStream();

 _currentString.listen((listOfStrings) {
    for (String myString in listOfStrings) {
      print(myString);
    }
 });
```